# How can I draw and ellipse and display it on Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I know that google maps provide API for drawing circles, polygons but not ellipse.

Does anyone know how to draw an ellipse, or can provide a link to an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [this extension](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/eshapes.htm) that provides the capabilities of drawing additional shapes.

[This example](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/example_eshapes.htm) uses the above mentioned extension.